# hg-to-hg and ConvertExtension Creates default branch under new repo

Tags: mercurial, branch

Env: Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.5.2+20130312) on Mac

I have a Mercurial repository with a structure like this:

```
repoOriginal
|__ file1
|__ foodir
|______file2
|______file3
```

I use this command.

```
hg convert -s hg -d hg repoOriginal
```

And I get this repository after the conversion:

```
repoOriginal-hg
|__ default
|____ file1
|____ foodir
|________file2
|________file3
```

I was expecting this repository:

```
repoOriginal-hg
|__ file1
|__ foodir
|______file2
|______file3
```

I must be doing something wrong. Is there away to prevent the conversion from converting the branch into a directory in the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested the same setup on Ubuntu and I don't see this problem. I've concluded it is an issue with my Mac env.

Answer (score 0):

The default branch exists in all Hg repositories.  It is a fundamental part of Hg's architecture.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But it doesn't appear as a directory in the repo which is what happens after the conversion.  There is nothing in the ConvertExtension docs about this; nor in any of the docs about using the extension I've been able to find.